# Memory leak in PHP worker

Tags: php, memory-leaks, xhprof

I have workers in PHP under supervisor.

And I have memory leak.. I use "xhprof" for tacking some information.
But I still cannot find anything.

If I restart worker - it's all fine, but then the problem started again :(

Any ideas concerning how I can find any information in "xhprof"?

Comment: Can I clear php memory at the loop end?